# CentOS8 SSH Public Key auth and Nginx

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, nginx, authentication

I have an issue with making SSH pubkey auth work the way I'd like and I don't know if it's possible to make it work or not.

I have a few websites hosted under different `/home/$USER`. All webfiles are under `/home/$USER/www`. Problem is, in order for nginx to be able to access webfiles (mostly PHP files and statics), ownership of `/home/$USER` has to be `nginx:nginx`. But now if any of those users want to auth with their SSH keys (whitelisted in `authorized_keys` under `/home/$USER/.ssh`), they can't as their `/home/$USER` is owned by `nginx:nginx` and not by `$USER:$USER`.

Is there any way to make it work? It's probably worth saying that websites has to be placed under different `/home/$USER` directories and not under `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

I'm using CentOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow through [NGINX and PHP-FPM. What my permissions should be?](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be).

In order to have a working (and secure) setup, PHP-FPM pool user has to run with the respective usernames that belongs to websites.

The `nginx:nginx` for site files' ownership is never a good idea.

Instead, files are owned by separate website users (different for each websites).
For NGINX to be able to read the files, what you need is to add `nginx` user to each website user's group:

```
usermod -a -G example nginx
```

Then `nginx` user can read website files of `example` user (under its home dir).

Comment: Thanks, it was wrongly configured PHP-FPM. I followed your article and got that part right. Never used PHP-FPM before. This solves my problem completely. Thank you very much!